# How to write a string in pdf file on specific path.. DOMPDF

Tags: php, dompdf

I have a function which takes two parameters data(html),name. In the function i am trying to save the data in **PDF** file on my *localhost/abc-folder*. Unfortunately it runs fine but don't write in specific file or so..

**Here is my code.**

```
<?php
function pdf($data, $name) {
  if (count($name) > 1) {
    $name = "Orders";
  } else {
    $name = 'Order_'.$name[0]['order_id'];
  }

  $pdf = new DOMPDF;
  $pdf->load_html($data);
  $pdf->render();
  $str=$pdf->output();

  $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/aabcd.pdf","wb");
  fwrite($fp,$str);
  fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: This question is better, but you should have cleaned up [your original one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30235251/264628) instead of asking a new one.

Comment: Do you get any errors? If you don't see any you may have to enable error logging or set PHP to send errors to the browser.

Comment: What is the "b" for in your mode? It doesn't appear to be valid based on the [documentation for `fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).