# How can I Send HTML outputs to an email as a PDF using DOMPDF

Tags: php, html, pdf, phpmailer, dompdf

I'm using this library from Dompdf, after showing the file as a PDF I want to send it to my email, I have tried several methods but I have not found a solution so far.

Thanks in advance

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml(html_entity_decode($output));
$dompdf->setPaper('A4');
$dompdf->render(); // Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->stream($invoiceFileName, array("Attachment" => false));
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: @waterloomatt these things : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958416/dompdf-attach-created-pdf-to-email

Comment: @KJ can you provide us an example please? How we can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this way will work for you:

```
<?php

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml(html_entity_decode($output));
$dompdf->setPaper('A4');
$dompdf->render(); // Render the HTML as PDF

// https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage#output
$output = $dompdf->output();

// Save PDF Document
file_put_contents('Document.pdf', $output);

// Use PHPMailer
// $mail->isSMTP();
// $mail->Host = 'smtp.example.org';
// $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
// $mail->Username = 'alice';
// $mail->Password = '123456'
// $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
// $mail->Port = 25;
$mail->addAttachment('Document.pdf');
$mail->send();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I gather from [the DOMPDF docs](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage#output) that you can get a PDF binary string without saving it to a file by doing this:

```
$pdfData = $dompdf->output();
```

and then you can pass that directly to PHPMailer as a string attachment so your PDF data never has to be written to a temporary file:

```
$mail-addStringAttachment($pdfData, 'file.pdf');
```

PHPMailer will take care of the encoding and MIME type for you.